# Twinkling images in a component

Tags: reactjs

I have component with navigation, on click item to child component passed in props some params, one of params - object 'itemImage' with className and url, like this:

```
{
    url: '/static/image.svg',
    className: 'absolute hidden md:block min-w-53 lg:min-w-68 mt-30 lg:mt-19 -ml-28 lg:-ml-75',
}
```

In child component ItemComponent:

```
{
     itemImage &&
     <img className={itemImage.className} src={itemImage.url} alt='' />
}
```

`ItemComponent` is selected from an array according to the order of the element in navigation (it is responsible for the object passed to the child component), since the list of navigation elements and elements of the array of pictures are not related and of different lengths. The sample is implemented on the basis of an index in map for objects and an index in an array with pictures, to be more precise.

**Problem:**
the pictures flicker as the state of the parent and the child is updated, is it possible to somehow avoid this and make the change of the picture clear without the flickering of the previous card.

Comment: are you updating anything in image object while changing the state if no then it should not flickering

Comment: new props from the parent come to the component, the main one is a new product, say, from which its description is taken and the object with parameters for drawing the image

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/7OSyfTBGrAcC6VIr?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview Please check this as state updated image not flickering

Comment: not necessary, any state change it will not update the actual dom until it will not find any change in it

Comment: I tried through the state of the parent the problem remained, unfortunately I can’t post all the code, probably I incorrectly state the problem

Comment: it's ok but keep in mind that if you will not change any specific value from the setState method it will not update it on the browser even if other values changed in the setState method. and if it still it's updating then please check your setState method by mistake you may update the value

Comment: I reorganized the code so that the array with img tags is already in my child and I just take the value from it by the index that comes in props from the parent, the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188657/discussion-between-dhaval-patel-and-roman-kovalevsky).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below-mentioned code to render the Array of Images.

```
  <>
            {this.props.Images.map(item=>{
                return (item)
            })}
             <p>
               {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
            </p>
            <p>
               {JSON.stringify(this.props.changed)}
            </p>
            <button onClick={this.props.onChange}>Change</button>
            <button onClick={this.onCurrentChange}>Current State Change</button>
        </>
```

Please check the demo here [Demo](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/7OSyfTBGrAcC6VIr?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can make somethings to try to prevent that.

1- Add a key prop to the elements. It help react understand that it is the same data from before and not re-render that piece.

2- Use react PureComponent on the flickering element https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent to prevent the re-render

3 - Instead of purecomponent implement shouldComponentUpdate